# Apple Push Notifications and Feedback for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need some help.

I have been struggling with creating a push notification script for APNS. I found some tutorials but i haven't really understood all the steps described there.

One major fallback is that all of them tell me that i should have an apple developer account, which is NOT free of charge, but i only need to to test this function.

So regarding the previous facts, i have a few questions:

1) Does anyone have a C# working sample code for implementing these push notifications? (with the steps required --- saw in a few tutorials that it requires a certificate, but don't know really how it should be formed)

2) Is there any way of verifying if a device token is invalid?

Best regards,
Ionut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have an Apple developer's account in order to create a push certificate, which is required for sending Apple Push Notifications to an iOS application. You'll also need such an account to develop the application.

There's a server-side C# library called [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) for sending push notifications to several platforms, including iOS.

There are two types of invalid device tokens :

1. A device token that was never valid in the push environment you are using (either production or sandbox). When you send a push notification with such an invalid token, you'll get a response from Apple indicating it's invalid.
2. A valid device token that belongs to a device from which your application was uninstalled - such device tokens are returned by the APNS Feedback service.

Comment: I downloaded and tried to test the PushSharp library. What i can't seem to succeed is with that certificate that i need. Isn't there any way of having that without that particular developer account?

Comment: @MariusPopa No there isn't. You must have a developer account to create the certificate (unless you are developing server side for sending Apple Push Notifications to some 3rd party app which you are not developing, in which case the developers of that app should create the certificate for you). The certificate is tied to a specific application.